# Assertion failure in -[UITextFieldLabel setTextColor:]

Tags: uitextfield, textfield, categories

i got following assertion failure :

Assertion failure in -[UITextFieldLabel setTextColor:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UILabel.m:314

at this line

***[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];***

in appDidFinishLaunching method.

```
    Unhandled exception: Debug info are

    Invalid parameter not satisfying: color
    (
"4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x991331fe _Z19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 15",
"5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x99133268 __cxa_bad_typeid + 0",
"6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x991342a0 _Z23__gxx_exception_cleanup19_Unwind_Reason_CodeP17_Unwind_Exception + 0",
"7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0167e416 __objc_personality_v0 + 0",
"8   CoreFoundation                      0x0182cef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136"
  )
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I finally found the cause of the issue.

It looks as [UILabel setTextColor:] crashes on (only!) iOS 4.x when a nil color is passed as parameter. My app runs fine on iOS 5 and 6.

I am using a navigationBar, created with IB which has a UITextField in it (which is, as usual, a subview of an BarButtonItem). This TextField had a TextColor attribute left to it default value. For TextFields which are placed on a normal view, this works fine but not for my TextField in a navigationBar. Once I changed the TextColor to anything else (e.g. Dark Text Color) works fine and doesn't cause any further crash.

It was hard to track down this issue as it happens at App startup and by the time when all NIB files are loaded so debugging the code or exception breakpoints didn't work. Even the crash log didn't help as it just tells you that it happens while loading a NIB file but doesn't tell you which one. In my case, there a quite a few views being loaded at startup. I was finally able track down the issue by creating a class category of the UILabel Class and just added a `-(void )setTextColor:(UIColor *)color` method to this category. In this method, I was then able to set a breakpoint and found that the parameter was nil in only one case. In addition, I then added `-(void )setText:(NSString *)text` and watched which text was set for this particular UILabel where the color was previously set no nil. The text parameter finally pointed me to my UITextField in the navigationBar.

Maybe this helps in other cases, where this crash is not related to a UITextField in an UINavigationBar.

Comment: did you sove the issue in the end? how to fix that nil UIcolor?

Comment: in my case the problem was caused by a UiTextField which was not embeded in any UiNavigationBar or UIToolbar. It was just a simple UITextField in xib. Yes, I solved the problem by setting the text  color to some other than default.